# TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object Regular expression removing special characters

Tags: python, pandas

train dataframe with content column. content column has list for each row containing different words in that list.

```
content
[sure, tune, …, watch, donald, trump, “,”, late, ’ , night]
[abc, xyz, “,”,late, ’, night]
```

Code to remove regular expressions

```
import re
train['content'] = train['content'].map(lambda x: re.sub(r'\W+', '', x))
```

Error

```
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

Expected output

```
content
[sure, tune,  watch, donald, trump, late,   night]
[abc, xyz,late, night]
```

Notice all the special characters like `...`, `“`, `”` and `’` are gone and we are left only with words.

Comment: First off - each row of content must be a string itself, not an actual list, otherwise you'd have syntax errors before you even started, should probably clarify that.

Comment: each row of content is a list

Comment: Are all of the items in the list defined variables then?  Either the list itself has to be a string, the items have to be strings / numbers, or they are variables that are previously defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to apply regular expression to the List object.

If your goal is to use this regex on every item of the list, you can apply re.sub for each item in list:

```py
import re
def replace_func(item):
    return re.sub(r'\W+', '', item)

train['content'] = train['content'].map(lambda x: [replace_func(item) for item in x])
```

Comment: Does not work.......this is separating all the individual letters

Comment: It would separate individual letters if there are strings in your content field. I assumed that all elements in the content field is a list. What does train.content.map(type).value_counts() shows?

Answer (score 0):

Just do:

```
content=['sure', 'tune', '…', 'watch', 'donald', 'trump', '“,”', 'late', '’' , 'night']
content = list(map(lambda x: re.sub(r'\W+', '', x),content))
```

Comment: content is a column in dataset. there are 30,000 rows in content column....these 2 rows are just an eg

Comment: main idea is to parse strings by regex isn't it? Do content=train['content'].tolist() and do back reassign or do foreach on dataframe column; you need additional conversion anyway in my opinion.